# Apache2 Alias not working in Ubuntu?

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-12.04

I've just setup apache/php/mysql in Ubuntu 12.04, and I've created an Alias for my virtual directory, here's my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default file:

```
Alias /demo/ "/home/czetsuya/projects/eclipse/eclipse-php/demo-portfolio"
<Directory "/home/czetsuya/projects/eclipse/eclipse-php/demo-portfolio">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Note that I've already applied chown and chmod to: /home/czetsuya/projects/eclipse/eclipse-php/demo-portfolio

```
chown www-data:www-data /home/czetsuya/projects/eclipse/eclipse-php/demo-portfolio -R
chmow 777 /home/czetsuya/projects/eclipse/eclipse-php/demo-portfolio -R
```

But when I access: _http://localhost/demo, I got a 404 Not found error. Looking at /var/log/apache2/error.log I found that it's still pointing at /var/www/demo:

```
File does not exist: /var/www/demo
```

Any idea why Alias is ignored?

Note that I already restart and reload apache2. And rewrite is also enabled.

Thanks,

czetsuya

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem can most likely be solved by the [mod_alias manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html);

> Note that if you include a trailing / on the URL-path then the server
>   will require a trailing / in order to expand the alias. That is, if
>   you use
>
> Alias /icons/ /usr/local/apache/icons/ then the URL /icons will not be
>   aliased, as it lacks that trailing /.

Try changing `/demo/` to `/demo` in your alias, and it should work better.

Comment: can you kindly have a look at this - https://serverfault.com/q/1019326/577137

Answer (score 11):

All aliases in Apache 2.4 have to be configured in the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.conf` file.

They are ignored in the virtual host files.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Installing Apache on Ubuntu 22.04**

 **Apache2** is an open-source popular, powerful, reliable, and highly extensible web/HTTP server software used by numerous websites on the internet.

To install the **Apache2** package, use the default package manager as follows:

```
 $ sudo apt install apache2  <br><br>
```

[image]

The configuration files for **Apache2** are located in **/etc/apache2** directory and the main configuration file is **strong text**/etc//etc/apache2/apache2.conf. And the default document root for storing your web files is **/var/www/html/.**

**2.** On **Ubuntu** unlike on other major Linux distributions, **systemd** services are automatically started and enabled to start at system boot, when a package (intended to run as a service) installation is complete.

You can confirm that the **Apache2** service is up and enabled on boot using the following systemctl commands.

```
 $ sudo systemctl status apache2 <br>
 $ sudo systemctl is-enabled apache2
```

[image]

**3.** Next, you need to test the correct operation of the Apache2 server installation. Open a web browser and use the following address to navigate.

```
http://YOUR_SERVER_IP
```

Answer (score 0):

guy take care about exact syntax of these SLASHES
it can not be at the end of directory name and also not at the end of alias name, this cost me unbelivable time to find this error, very good work people from apache !!!
proper way :
Alias "/docs" "/var/web"
wrong way:
Alias "/docs/" "/var/web/"