# Configuring Alias and Directory inside Apache VirtualHost

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

I have an existing subdomain, subdomain.mysite.com, that I use with SSL. I'm trying to install [PHPasswordPusher](https://github.com/bemosior/PHPasswordPusher) on this subdomain, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly with Apache.

I've followed the instructions as provided. For example, the DocumentRoot for subdomain.mysite.com is `/var/www/subdomain`, and the two pwpusher directories are in `/var/www/ppush`. I've added the code exactly as given in the installation instructions to the appropriate VirtualHost, and I've edited the code as specified to point to the proper directories for everything. I'm getting a 404, however, when I try to go to the Alias directory on the subdomain. (Yes, I restarted Apache.)

How do I get the given Apache config to work within an existing VirtualHost? The full code for the VirtualHost is below, edited for the locations I've given above.

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
        ServerName subdomain.mysite.com

        ServerAdmin emailaddress@host.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/cert2.pem

    ##### PHPasswordPusher #####

        Alias /pwpusher/ /var/www/ppush/pwpusher_public/

        <Directory /var/www/ppush/pwpusher_public/>
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            DirectoryIndex pw.php
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/ppush/pwpusher_private/>
            AllowOverride None
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Everything with the configuration looks OK, except `*:80` for the `VirtualHost` which would generate "bad request" error, but would not be the reason for 404 error. A bit crude, but you can try to understand what directory Apache really accesses by running `strace -p $(pgrep apache2 | xargs | sed 's/ / -p /g')` and open the page. On one of the last lines you should see something like `stat("/var/www/dsd", 0x7fff470d2400) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: @user3584460 That's an awesome command, thank you! It appears to be completely ignoring the `Alias` though--the command reports this: `[pid  1228] lstat("/var/www/subdomain/pwpusher", 0x7ffcc44c90f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`. Using that information I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189261/apache2-alias-not-working-in-ubuntu); removing the trailing `/` fixed my problem. If you want to post this as an answer I'm more than happy to give you credit/the bounty. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything with the configuration looks OK, except `*:80` for the `VirtualHost` which would generate "Bad request" error when the URL is opened with `http://` (I advise you to move the SSL directives to `<VirtualHost *:443>`), but would not be the reason for 404 error.

A bit crude, but you can try to understand what directory Apache really accesses by running

```
strace -p $(pgrep apache2 | xargs | sed 's/ / -p /g')
```

and open the page. On one of the last lines you should see something like:

```
stat("/var/www/dsd", 0x7fff470d2400) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: For anyone who reads this comment and not the original comments, here's what I posted above: That's an awesome command, thank you! It appears to be completely ignoring the `Alias` though--the command reports this: `[pid 1228] lstat("/var/www/subdomain/pwpusher", 0x7ffcc44c90f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`. Using that information I found this question; removing the trailing `/` fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: It ignores the Alias directive because Rewrite directives override any Alias directives.  This is mentioned in the Apache documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html